# Python multiprocessing: checking if the memory is shared or being replicated

Tags: python, python-multithreading, python-multiprocessing, pathos

I have to query a large a number of vectors from a sklearn KDTree, which is path of searcher class. I am trying to query them in parallel, using python multiprocessing, however the parallel code takes almost the same (or more) time as the single version.

```
import time, numpy as np
from sklearn.neighbors import KDTree
from multiprocessing import Pool

def glob_query(arg, **kwarg):
    return Searcher.query(*arg, **kwarg)

class Searcher:
    def __init__(self, N, D):
            self.kdt = KDTree(np.random.rand(N,D), leaf_size=30, metric="euclidean")

    def query(self, X):
            return self.kdt.query(X, k=5, return_distance=False)

    def query_sin(self, X):
            return [self.query(x) for x in X]

    def query_par(self, X):
            p = Pool(4)
            return p.map(glob_query, zip([self]*len(X), X))

if __name__=="__main__":
    N = 1000000     # Number of points to be indexed
    D = 50          # Dimensions
    searcher = Searcher(N, D)

    E = 100         # Number of points to be searched
    points = np.random.rand(E, D)

    # Works fine
    start = time.time()
    searcher.query_sin(points)
    print("Time taken - %f"%(time.time()-start))

    # Slower than single core
    start = time.time()
    print searcher.query_par(points)
    print("Time taken - %f"%(time.time()-start))

Time taken - 28.591089
Time taken - 36.920716
```

I want to know

- if my kd-tree is being copied across each worker thread
- is there an alternate way to parallelise search (using pathos?)

Answer (score 2):

I'm the `pathos` author.  As stated in the other answers, `multiprocessing` copies the object to the new process. The same will be the case with `pathos`, as it's built on a fork of `multiprocessing`.  `pathos` can help you in (1) it will provide better serialization, (2) a more flexible `map` that can take multiple arguments, and (3) removes some overhead when starting multiple `Pool`… but this doesn't sound like your case.

If the computations are really light individually, then maybe threads in `multiprocessing.dummy` are a better way to go.  You can try it, and see if it speeds things up.  The interface is the same, so there's little to edit in your code.  Also, as others suggest, if you don't need to maintain the order of your results, `imap_unordered` is often the fastest of the `map` functions on a `Pool`.

Often the best thing to do is just try several kinds of `map`, and see which is fastest for your case.

Comment: I tried `multiprocessing.dummy`, it's definitely faster than `multiprocessing`, however not faster than single core method (I guess that's expected as only 1 thread is executed at a time). I'll try out `imap_unordered`.

Answer (score 1):

The `Pool` starts processes which are basically a copy of the parent process at that time. Since you create kd-tree before the pool, all children should have it.

Note that creating new processes takes time and memory.

Every time the mapped function returns a result, that result is being sent back to the parent process using IPC. Depending on the size of the data that is returned, this can have significant overhead.

But before you try to improve, **measure**. You cannot fix a problem if you don't know what causes it.

You could use a profiler to see where the program spends its time.

Or you could use `imap` or `imap_unordered` which returns an iterator over the results. Print the time just before starting the `imap`. Print the current time before and after running a query in the `query` method. Also print the time when the iterator yields a result. That should give you an idea about where the program is spending most of its time.

Answer (score 1):

Well your code seems fine. I guess the extra time comes from creating the 4 processes in the pool. Try creating the pool in the Searcher's init method to see if it really is the case.

About your question, when you open a new process, the passed object is copied to the new process.

If you run it in Windows than every process you start will cause python to reimport all your code in the new process, and pickle your variables in order to copy them (this may be expensive for short running processes)

In linux all of this is replaced with os.fork

Comment: If I create pool in `init`, I get an error saying `pool objects cannot be passed between processes or pickled`

Comment: @kampta: if you *do* end up needing to pass a `pool`, you can do so with `pathos`… essentially, you can make nested `map` calls (or `map` variants).